# Accept all incoming requests on a ServerSocket

Tags: java, sockets, ip-address, dhcp

I'm temporarily using the following line to create a ServerSocket on my Android phone:

```
socketl = new ServerSocket(port, 0, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.108"));
```

But it's really annoying and, besides, not user-friendly to change the IP address manually every time the DHCP assigns a new IP to the phone. So I'm searching for a way to get the IP-Address the DHCP-Server gave to my phone.

Ive tries `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()`, but that only returned the IPv4 loopback (`127.0.0.1`).

Is there a way to either get the current local IP(v4) or a way to accept every request, no matter which IP is used to connected? If the IP-Address in the line above isn't the same as the one the client uses, it doesn't work.

Comment: You did read the [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket%28int,%20int,%20java.net.InetAddress%29), did you?

Comment: I was using a tutorial which didn't mention anything else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
socketl = new ServerSocket(port, 0);
```

or even

```
socketl = new ServerSocket(port);
```